# jQuery dropdownlist does not return correct selection

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-select

Does anyone know why this is happening? From my controller (FirmsController) I am simply trying to get the selected firm back to the controller method (EditAffiliations(string selectedFirm)) as a parameter. The selected firm value is supposed to come from a dropdownlist. But no matter what I do, I cant seem to get this right. I am new, I'll admit that, but this is riduculous. Below is the method.

```
public ActionResult EditAffiliations(string selectedFirm)
    {
       // selectedFirm = "8";
        //All available firms
        //Collection<Firm> firms = new Collection<Firm>();
        //Collection<FirmSelectorModel> models = new Collection<FirmSelectorModel>();

        var model = new FirmSelectorModel();
        _workContext.CurrentUser.Firms = _firmService.GetAllFirms().Where(m => m.ExternalId.Contains("F")).ToArray();

        if (selectedFirm==null || _workContext.CurrentFirm == null)
        {
            _workContext.CurrentFirm = _workContext.CurrentUser.Firms.FirstOrDefault();
            model.CurrentFirm = _workContext.CurrentFirm.ToModel();
        }
        else
        {
            model.CurrentFirm = _firmService.GetFirmById(Convert.ToInt16(selectedFirm)).ToModel(); //_workContext.CurrentFirm.ToModel();
        }

        model.AvailableFirms = (_firmService.GetAllFirms().Where(m => m.ExternalId.Contains("F"))).Select(x => x.ToModel()).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Below is my view:

```
@model FirmSelectorModel
@using System.Globalization;
@{
var gridPageSize = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<Incendo.Core.Domain.Common.AdminAreaSettings>().GridPageSize;
}

@T("Admin.Users.UserAffiliations")

@if (Model.AvailableFirms.Count > 0)
{
using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditAffiliations", "Firms", new AjaxOptions { OnComplete = "onFirmChangedRequestCompleted();" }, new { id = "form-firmselector", role = "form"}))
{
    var firms = Model.AvailableFirms.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = String.Format("{0} - {1}", x.ExternalId, x.Name),
        Value = x.Id.ToString(),
        Selected = x.Id.Equals(Model.CurrentFirm.Id)
    });

    @Html.DropDownList("userfirm",
        firms,
        new { onChange = "onFirmChanged();", @class = "form-control"})
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onFirmChanged() {
        //var singleValues = $("#userfirm").val();
        //$("#form-firmselector").submit();
        //alert(singleValues);


    }
    function onFirmChangedRequestCompleted() {
        //location.reload();
    }

    $("select").change(displayVals);
    displayVals();
</script>
}
```

I want the value selected in the dropdwonlist to be returned back to the controller. What am I supposed to write in the function onFirmchanged()? How to send it back to the controller?
What am I missing? Hopefully someone will answer before I lose my friggin' mind with this annoyance...
Regards, SM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your HTML markup:

```
<option value="cat">dog</option>
<option value="dog">cat</option>
```

Should be:

```
<option value="dog">dog</option>
<option value="cat">cat</option>
```

A dog is a dog, a cat is a cat...

Comment: Hi, yeah, I am sorry about that. This is true. If the code in fiddle works then wy does it not work in my code? I want the value selected in the dropdwonlist to be returned back to the controller. What am I supposed to write in the function onFirmchanged()? How to send it back to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uds9w/15/)**

```
<option value="dog">dog</option>
<option value="cat">cat</option>
```